# RuntimeException: Unknown comparator 'CompositeType'

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax, column-family

I need to create CompositeColumns in a Cassandra ColumnFamily.

Each column value will store the something like this-

```
user-id   column1
123      (Column1-Value  Column1-SchemaName  LastModifiedDate)
```

same with column2 as well and other columns as well. So I decided to go with something like this-

Below is the description for the columns-

```
ByteType for Column-Value
UTF8Type for Column-SchemaName
DateType for LastModifiedDate
```

I created the below columnfamily like this-

```
create column family USER_DATA
with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and comparator = 'CompositeType(ByteType,UTF8Type,DateType)'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and gc_grace = 86400
and column_metadata = [ {column_name : 'lmd', validation_class : DateType}];
```

Let me know if this is the right way to create the above column family?

But as soon as I try to execute the above column, I always get the below error.

```
[default@userks]     create column family USER_DATA
...         with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
...         and comparator = 'CompositeType(ByteType,UTF8Type,DateType)'
...         and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
...         and gc_grace = 86400
...         and column_metadata = [ {column_name : 'lmd', validation_class : DateType}];

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown comparator 'CompositeType(ByteType,UTF8Type,DateType)'. Available functions: bytes, integer, long, int, lexicaluui
d, timeuuid, utf8, ascii, double, countercolumn.
```

Can anybody help me with this?

**Update:-**

I just found out about that error, I forgot to add extra `s` in ByteType.

Below is the ColumnFamily-

```
create column family USER_DATA
with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and comparator = 'CompositeType(BytesType,UTF8Type,DateType)'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and gc_grace = 86400
and column_metadata = [ {column_name : 'lmd', validation_class : DateType}];
```

Below is the error I got..

```
[default@beprofileks]     create column family USER_DATA
...         with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
...         and comparator = 'CompositeType(BytesType,UTF8Type,DateType)'
...         and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
...         and gc_grace = 86400
...         and column_metadata = [ {column_name : 'lmd', validation_class : DateType}];

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: cannot parse 'lmd' as hex bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `BytesType`, not `ByteType`:

```
CompositeType(BytesType,UTF8Type,DateType)
```

The other problem is that `lmd` is not a valid column name for the comparator `CompositeType(BytesType,UTF8Type,DateType)`. A valid name is, for example, `aa00:string:2013-09-19`.

Comment: My mistake. I just catch that error.. But after making that change, I am getting another exception. I edited my question as well.